# How to remove background borders in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, background

I'm still a beginner in programing. I have an issue I can't get rid of using Tkinter. The fact is that I'm using a background image for my root gui, I scaled it accordingly to my gui size and it works fine.
The issue is that, on paint.net, I removed the white pixels around the image borders, which makes its shape not totally rectangular. When I use it as a background image on Tkinter, as a .gif file, the white pixels I removed still appear on the gui. This wouldn't be a big issue if I was using the gui in normal state, but I used the command root.overrideredirect(1) to remove window borders which makes it look like this :
[what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkWYi.png)

[what I want without white borders(the image already has no borders, imgur somehow brought them back ,and there isnt any buttons because it's the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz8Ts.png)

Thanks by advance, and sorry if it was obvious or I did a major mistake.

EDIT : Apparently this is a Windows issue as for j_4321 it worked on Linux.
For Windows users, I found a quite good fix using these lines :

```
root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor","white")
root.configure(background='white')
```

and adding bg='white' to my label like this :

```
image_label=Label(root,image=your_image,bg='white')
```

Some white pixels might remain, if it does use .gif files. They seem to be easier to remove for Tkinter this way.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Have you tried to use a .png image instead of .gif? If you use python 3, tkinter supports png now, otherwise see http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm to include one using PIL.

Comment: I dont know exactly what's going on. Yesterday it told me .png wasn't supported, and right now it works with .png, though the white pixels didnt go off.

Comment: If you open your png in an image viewer, do you see the white pixels too?

Comment: to j_4321 : Nop, I removed them myself using paint.net.About PIL, I just looked at the link you provided me, and it seems like PIL isn't made for Python 3 which I use.

Comment: When I wrote PIL, I meant Pillow, which is a fork of PIL and works perfectly on both python 2 and 3: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/4.0.0.

Comment: Okay I had some issues installing Pillow, but now I made it (was my first time installing a module). However I tried : background_image = Image.open("bg_1680_1050_2.png")
background_label=Label(root,image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1) butit doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: I think you forgot one line of the code provided on http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm: `photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(background_image)`

Comment: Alright thanks it works, but the pixels still didn't go off. Is there some kind of arguments I need to add to the image?

Comment: I've been searching out and the white pixels are called alpha channels it seems. So i've tried some fixes I found but it doesnt seem to work. I tried : `red, green, blue, alpha = background_image.split()` and `alpha = background_image.split()[-1]` The white pixels still remained on the window

Comment: when I use a png with some transparent pixels, it works just fine, so I don't know what's wrong in your case. Have you tried with a different png image which contains transparent pixels?

Comment: I'll just give you my code because I dont see where the issue comes from, i'll put it on first message due to character limit. the image is set at 336*525 to fit my screen size and my conditions, for your image, resize it screen wide/5 and height/2

Comment: I tried your code with a png image instead of the gif you use and the background of the picture is transparent as expected. However, I am using python 3.6 with tk8.6 under linux.

Comment: I tried with a png file and it didn't work either, I am also using python 3.6 however under windows 7. Is it an issue linked to windows ? If you have any idea on how to get things working, tell me :) and thanks for paying attention to my issue !

Comment: Okay I tried many things since then, and apparently I was able to fix it somehow. It worked out by changing background color to white and background color of the label to white aswell and changing color to transparent. I added this `root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor","white")
root.configure(background='white')` and added bg=white like this to my label : `background_label=Label(root,image=photo,bg='white')`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem:

```
from Tkinter import *

app = Tk()
app.overrideredirect(True)
app.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
app.wm_attributes("-transparent", True)
app.config(bg='systemTransparent')

app.geometry("+300+300")

app.image = PhotoImage(file="ButtonBACKUP.gif")
label = Label(app, image=app.image)
label.config(bg='systemTransparent')

label.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

All this code does is it makes a label, then sets the label background to transparent, while cutting off the top.